# Skewed geography plotting census shapefiles in R

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf, rgdal, census

I've pulled US census data by block and merged the block shapefile on it manually with the `sf` and `rgdal` packages. When I plot the resulting `sf` object it's showing a skewed map despite the `crs` remaining the same from the read-in of the shapefile through the merge.

The shapefiles can be found here: https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER_RD18/LAYER/TABBLOCK20/, the one for Illinois that I'm using is `tl_rd22_17_tabblock20.zip`.

The census data can be found here: https://data.census.gov/table?q=population&g=0500000US17031$1000000&tid=DECENNIALPL2020.P1

Here's what should be a MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
library(data.table)

dt_census <- fread(path_to_census_data)

blck_shp <- readOGR(dsn = block_shapefile_filepath, layer = "tl_rd22_17tabblock20")

blck_sf <- st_as_sf(blck_shp)

dt <- merge(blck_sf,dt_census, by.x = "GEOID20", by.y = "GEOID")

mini_dt <- dt[,c("POP20","geometry")]
mini_dt$POP20 <- as.numeric(mini_dt$POP20)

plot(mini_dt)
```

but this produces a skewed plot where some blocks on the northeast are clearly outside of city lines and into Lake Michigan.

[image]

Comment: Looks fine - https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFrmR.png . You can apply land or water area filter (`ALND20` / `AWATER20`) if you want to remove those polygons.

Comment: Ah you're right, thank you! If you want to make this a reply I can flag it as the correct answer and close the thread.